# Does light travel same distance in same time not depending of the path orientation regarding Earth's surface?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, frame-dragging

Does light travel the same distance at the same time regardless of the path orientation? The light in the proximity of a gravitational source can bend its trajectory and frame-dragging can cause the speed of a light beam or material object is not same depending this trajectory is or is not retrograde. So if we accept the possibility of a light and matter carrier that can be dragged or moved as you want to say it, can it if it is doing a whirl or not but moving in direction of the gravitational source, cause the speed of light could be greater if the direction is from the sky towards Earth's surface than it would be if the direction were from the Earth's surface towards the sky?

Answer (score -1):

The speed of light is something like the primordial meter of distance, only for speed. If you are at any location, you always measure c. It doesn't matter whether the light is moving towards or against a gravitational source.

Viewed from a distant observer, however, the matter looks different. Light moves more slowly the greater the gravitational potential. Slower near a black hole than in interstellar space.

Comment: Do two beams of light orbiting the black hole in the black hole photon sphere, moving in opposite directions can feel frame dragging in that way that one orbits the black hole faster than the other one?